# Как исправить ошибку в цикле IndentationError: expected an indented block?

Tags: python, циклы

Задача обучить случайный лес с различным числом деревьев от 1 до 50 и для каждого из вариантов оценить качество работы полученного леса на кросс-валидации по 5 блокам. (sklearn.metrics.r2_score). Я написал такой цикл:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

P_scores = []
p = np.linspace(1.0, 50.0, num=50)
p1 = np.array(p)
kf = KFold(4176, n_folds=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

P = 0
while P < len(p1):
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=P, random_state=1)
regressor.fit(X, Y)
predictions = clf.predict(X)
r2_score(Y, predictions)
P_scores.append(r2_score)
print(P_scores)
P += 1
```

Но получается ошибка всегда одна и та же, какой бы я цикл не писал:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Как её исправить?

(я делал так же `for`цикл с индексами [P] но выходила всё та же ошибка)

**Обновление**

Правда, я писал код в блокноте и просто вставил в консоль без отступа. Код сработал, потому что ошибка получилась другая:

> ValueError: n_estimators must be greater than zero, got 0.

Но тут просто с 1 начать нужно.

Почему то вместо ожидаемого результата вектора содержащего оценки по итерациям. Я получил:

```
<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>
<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>
...
<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>
<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>
```

и при команде

```
min(r2_score)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
E = np.array(r2_score)
min(E)
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Comment: это чисто питоновская ошибка - надо правильно отфопматировать блок внутри `while` - должен быть отступ внутри блока. К machine-learning никакого отношения не имеет..

Comment: @user21 я бы рекомендовал Вам (до программирования машинного обучения) ознакомиться с основами синтаксиса языка.

Comment: Где можно взять необходимый минимум для этого? Книга Python for data anlysis подойдёт?

Comment: по-моему, имеет смысл переименовать и обновить вопрос, потому что в виде комментария это почти не "читабельно"...

Comment: @user21 "Dive into Python" M. Pilgrim

Comment: @andy.37 Вы могли бы порекомендовать, поделиться опытом, как наиболее эффективно ознакомится с синтаксисом и приступить к практике?

Comment: @MaxU  [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550276/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-r2-score-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)
Спасибо за рекомендацию MaxU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndentationError: expected an indented block = Ошибка отступа.

По стандартам PEP принято делать отступ в 4 пробела, но интерпретатор будет работать даже если выделять 1 пробелом, или знаком табуляции.

Код должен быть отформатирован. Внутри цикла должна визуально отображаться вложенность.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

P_scores = []
p = np.linspace(1.0, 50.0, num=50)
p1 = np.array(p)
kf = KFold(4176, n_folds=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

P = 0
while P < len(p1):
    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=P, random_state=1)
    regressor.fit(X, Y)
    predictions = clf.predict(X)
    r2_score(Y, predictions)
    P_scores.append(r2_score)
    print(P_scores)
    P += 1
```

Второй случай когда возникает данная ошибка это смешивание знака табуляции и пробелов. Например такое происходит если писать код в не настроенном редакторе Sublime Text

Пример с большим уровнем вложенности и как оно должно отображаться.

```
product = 0
for product in products:
    print(product)

    for attribute in product.specifications:
        print(attribute)

        if attribute['size']:
            for size in attribute['size']:
                try:
                    size * 2
                except:
                    size = 0
print("hello")
```