# Как получить числовые данные из переменной r2_score после выполнения цикла?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Задача обучить случайный лес с различным числом деревьев от 1 до 50 и для каждого из вариантов оценить качество работы полученного леса на кросс-валидации по 5 блокам  (`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`).

Написал такой цикл:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

P_scores = []
p = np.linspace(1.0, 50.0, num=50)
p1 = np.array(p)
kf = KFold(4176, n_folds=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

P = 1
while P < len(p1):
    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=P, random_state=1)
    regressor.fit(X, Y)
    predictions = regressor.predict(X)
    r2_score(Y, predictions)
    P_scores.append(r2_score)
    print(P_scores)
    P += 1
```

В итоге, получается вектор состоящий из элементов:

```
print(P_scores)
[<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>, <function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>,...,<function r2_score at 0x0000023304775BF8>]
```

Хотя я ожидал подобный результат:

```
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)  
0.948...
```

Только записанной в форме вектора столбца.
Естественно я не смогу узнать минимум:

```
min(P_scores)
TypeError: unorderable types: function() < function()
```

Почему я получаю не числовые данные? Как мне получить числовые параметры оценок?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте поменять:

```
r2_score(Y, predictions)
P_scores.append(r2_score)
```

на:

```
P_scores.append(r2_score(Y, predictions))
```

`P_scores.append(r2_score)` - добавляет в массив ссылку на функцию вместо возвращаемого значения(ий)

Демонстрация:

```
In [38]: y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]

In [39]: y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]

In [40]: from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
```

это ссылка на функцию:

```
In [41]: r2_score
Out[41]: <function sklearn.metrics.regression.r2_score>
```

а здесь мы получаем результат вызова функции с параметрами:

```
In [42]: r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
Out[42]: 0.94860813704496794
```